# Does the Senate need supermajority or just a regular majority to prevent a convicted President from running for office again?

Tags: united-states, president, constitution, senate, impeachment

The Constitution allows the Senate to punish an impeached President with prevention from holding an important office in the future, do they need 2/3rds of the Senate to do this or 2/3rds for a conviction but only a regular majority for assigning a punishment?

Comment: While the question is not a direct duplicate, the answer to the linked question fully answers this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in Panda's [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/61717/18373) to the linked q, the relevant precedent is

> The Constitution is silent on whether, after an official has already been impeached and removed from office, imposing the additional sanction of disqualification requires a supermajority vote. In the past, however, **the Senate determined that a simple majority vote is sufficient for disqualification. Judge Archibald was disqualified by a vote of 39-35 after he was removed from office.**
>
> To be clear, such a simple majority vote may only take place after the Senate has already voted to convict an impeached official. Two-thirds of the Senate must first agree to remove someone from office before that official can be disqualified — a simple majority cannot, acting on its own, disqualify an official from holding future office.

It refers to [Robert Wodrow Archbald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Wodrow_Archbald)
's impeachment in 1913 or so.