# What happens with the second impeachment now that Trump has left office?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, trump-impeachment

I know there has been talk already about whether or not a former president can be impeached. I have not, however, heard the practical ending to that talk. What happens with Trump's second impeachment (over the events of Jan 6 2021) now that he has left office (or will have left office come noon time)? Are there practical answers? All I've heard is theoretical discussion - but it is not a theoretical issue anymore.

Comment: See also https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/61831/1370

Comment: The linked answer is NOT a duplicate.  It asks whether a President can be impeached AFTER leaving office, but Trump was impeached BEFORE leaving.

Comment: @jamesqf The situations are barely distinguishable, and the answer is equally applicable to both.  If anything, impeached before and tried after is "more obviously legitimate and do-able" than impeached after and tried after, and the latter has already occurred (albeit for a non-president).

Comment: @zibadawa timmy: No, the situations are very different.  Whether it is technically legal to impeach someone after they've left office is irrelevant here (unless of course the House comes up with still another reason to impeach Trump), simply because Trump was impeached BEFORE leaving office.

Comment: @jamesqf Which is, again, not even remotely the point being made.  A trial has happened after the person has left office, wherein the Senate specifically ruled that they had jurisdiction for an impeachment trial of someone no longer in office.  And that impeachment had the demerit, relative to this situation, of the impeachment also technically occurring after the person had left office.

Comment: @zibadawa timmy: Certainly it is the point.  The question specifically asks "whether or not a former president can be impeached".  That is absolutely irrelevant to Trump's current impeachment, which happened while he was still President.  Now a proper question might well ask whether a President (or other official) who was impeached before leaving office can be tried after leaving office, which is the case withTrump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal impeachment procedure still applies. The Senate will hold a trial after the House sends the articles of impeachment over to the Senate. At the moment, it appears the articles will be sent to the Senate at the end of this week, with the trial being carried out the following week. From [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/US/democrats-weighing-witnesses-plan-launch-impeachment-trial-end/story?id=75339708):

> House Speaker Nancy Pelosi is expected to send the article of impeachment against President Donald Trump to the Senate later this week, sources familiar with the matter tell ABC News -- a move that could kick off formal proceedings the next day and opening arguments on the Senate floor the following week.
>
> The timing of formal transmission from the House to the Senate is significant, as the Constitution dictates that the trial begins at 1 p.m. the following day.

Specifics such as whether witnesses will be called are still being decided.

Also, it's worth noting that the vote to bar an individual from holding public office again comes *after* the vote to convict. As such, even if the vote to convict and remove a President is moot, the subsequent vote to bar the individual from holding public office again is not moot. See [If the senate cannot remove a federal official already out of office, how can they disqualify said person from running for office again?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61715/if-the-senate-cannot-remove-a-federal-official-already-out-of-office-how-can-th).

Comment: Potentially complicated by the rumour that the [Chief Justice](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/kamala-harris-trump-impeachment-justice-roberts-b1789692.html) doesn't want to be part of the process.

Comment: "any conviction will of course be moot, the Senate can choose whether to take a vote on whether to bar the President from running for future public offices": the conviction will not be moot, because they can only bar him from future office if they convict him.

Comment: @phoog Thanks again. I copied over an unambiguous paragraph from [my other answer regarding that](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61715/if-the-senate-cannot-remove-a-federal-official-already-out-of-office-how-can-th).

Comment: I hope I hope I hope they call witnesses and they call that ...person ... QAnon...whatever his real name is. Every time a news program shows the video of the mob inside and that ... person ... is up in the gallery howling, it causes me to wonder at humanity's fall into idiocracy-like norms.

Comment: But as far as I can tell, this just relies on speculation by the news network.  It would seem reasonable to postpone the sending, and thus the start of the trial, to allow time for more investigation into how much pre-planning of the Capitol attack there was, and to what extent Trump was involved.

Comment: @Jontia Not complicated at all. Impeachments are purely political processes. The only reason you'd involve a court is to try and block the proceedings, but there's simply no room for that. It's a matter entirely internal to Congress.

Comment: @CGCampbell: I **sincerely** doubt there is any actual person behind the 'Q' facade. In all likelihood, 'Q' is mythological: an avatar created by someone to spread particular some malicious rumor that later took on a life of its own, and to which conspiracy theorists now attribute things that are too crazed for them to say in their own voice. Think of Q as the dark web Santa Claus, an imaginary figure who gives gifts of salacious and depraved rumor to all the bad little boys and girls who need them.

Comment: @Jontia And going from what is reported on that, it's a weirdly political stance for him to take.  Because his objection apparently isn't some sort of "the constitution doesn't allow this impeachment" or "I'm not required to preside over an ex-president's impeachment" opinion, but rather a "some on the left tried to co-opt me onto their side last time and I don't wanna go through that again".  To which I say: suck it up, buttercup. The tradition of SCOTUS to position itself as apolitical doesn't get thrown to the wind because the other branches don't care. It's there, always, despite it.

Comment: @Harabeck it isn't about involving the court. Presiding over presidential impeachment trials is a listed job of the Chief Justice.

Comment: @TedWrigley Maybe I used the wrong name. I was talking about that ... person ... who insists on wearing the fur hat with horns, who was up in the gallery howling.

Comment: @CGCampbell: Oh you mean the self-professed Q-Shaman: *THAT* guy. I get your point; sorry I misunderstood.  